# forcing a button to swap the images

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

I'm working on a matching program for iPad and when a user selects a button an image is "uncovered" and then when the user selects a second button,another image is uncovered. I then programmatically check for a match and if not, revert both button images back to their initial state.

This is working fine except when a match is NOT made, the switch happens so fast that you do not have time to see what you have "uncovered".  I tried to make it sleep but the image doesn't ever swap to the uncovered state... Thoughts?

The code for this is as follows:

```
//Take action on the tap of one of the buttons
if(isFirstSelection)
{
    firstSelection = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
    tempImageItem = [tileArray objectAtIndex:firstSelection];
    tempImage = [tempImageItem tileImage];
    firstSelectionName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[tempImageItem tileName]];
    [(UIButton *)sender setImage:tempImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    tempButton = sender;
    isFirstSelection = NO;       
}else{
    secondSelection = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
    tempImageItem = [tileArray objectAtIndex:secondSelection];
    tempImage = [tempImageItem tileImage];
    secondSelectionName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[tempImageItem tileName]];
    [(UIButton *)sender setImage:tempImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Two game pieces have been removed so check to see if they are a match
    if([firstSelectionName isEqualToString:secondSelectionName])
    {
        //Match found
        //do something

    }else{
        **//NO MATCH FOUND 
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3]; 
        //Display the checker board pieces again 
        [(UIButton *)sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"originalImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];** 

    }
    //Reset isFirstSelection Flag to YES for next selection
    isFirstSelection = YES;           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you want to put the button's original image after 3 seconds so the user has the time to see what happened.
You should look at the NSTimer class to trigger that code

```
[(UIButton *)sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"originalImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

in 3 seconds from now.

Comment: Yes, agreed.  I didn't want to just spin but I was just trying different things hoping something would work. Bogatyr's solution worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

For "run this code in X seconds" I prefer:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(spinWheel:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:0] afterDelay:delay];
```

no need to muck around with timer objects.

Comment: You're welcome!   On stack overflow you show your appreciation and help fellow askers by accepting the answer that works for you.